# How do I return callback of MySQL query and push to an array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I'm trying to populate an array using a MYSQL query on a table that takes all rows and pushes the rows to WordList.

I can print each line within the method fine, but when I go out of the scope of that method it doesn't push anything to Wordlist.

```
function getParrotMessage() {

    wordList = [];

    console.log(wordList);

    // Implementation
    getWord('result', function (err, result) {

        console.log(result); // works, prints the row data in MySQL table
        wordList.push(result); // doesn't work

    });

    console.log(wordList);
    return parrot_message;
}

// Method
function getWord(word, callback) {
    var query = con.query('SELECT * FROM word_table');
    query.on('result', function (row) {
        callback(null, row.word);
    });
};
```

wordlist: []

wordlist shows up as an empty array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, just beginning with javascript and node.js

Comment: Your method `getWord` is **asynchronous** ! So the second `console.log(wordList);` is printed before any results are returned (before you even call `wordList.push(result);` for the first time)

Comment: So how can I actually retrieve that result data so I can manipulate it and do various other thing. I don't need to print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method getWord is **asynchronous**!

So the second `console.log(wordList);` is printed before any results are returned (before you even call `wordList.push(result);` for the first time)

Also since you query db(which is asynchronous) in *getParrotMessage* function you need to use callback (or Promise or whatever else there is that can be used) instead of return statement.

```
function getParrotMessage(callback) {

    getWord('result', function (err, result) {

        if(err || !result.length) return callback('error or no results');
        // since result is array of objects [{word: 'someword'},{word: 'someword2'}] let's remap it
        result = result.map(obj => obj.word);
        // result should now look like ['someword','someword2']
        // return it
        callback(null, result);

    });
}

function getWord(word, callback) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM word_table', function(err, rows) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, rows);
    });
};
```

now use it like this

```
getParrotMessage(function(err, words){
    // words => ['someword','someword2']

});
```